# Is my cat dead?

Tags: bmw, catalytic-converter

My car is a 2003 bmw e46 with 2.2 petrol engine. Just bought an elm 327 Bluetooth scanner and did some testing with it. Below are some graphs made with ScanMaster app.
This is lambda output voltages then car was idling(engine was fully heated).
[image: Lamda output hot idle]

Then I raised rpms to 2000 and got this graphs:
[image: Lamda output 2k rpms]

Finaly I raised rpms to 3000:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you getting any codes? What's getting you to look at these in the first place? Have you tested the heat input/output of the cat itself? This can tell you if the cat is dead or not (and not an issue with the sensor).

Comment: Hello! I get sometimes lean codes on both banks. Didn't check cats temperature, thanks for hint. Car sometimes doesn't accelerate good under load(for example then going uphill from stop light).

Comment: What I've looked for with cat operation is the steadiness of the output. If the cat isn't functioning and the sensor is good, the output of sensor 2 will almost mirror the output of sensor 1 from the same side. In the second set of outputs from B2S2, there is a little variation, but nothing like what you are seeing from B2S1.

Comment: Someone said that it should be staying near 0.7 V. As you see in first image, one sensor stays at 0.1V. What do you think has more probability: bad sensor or cat not working?

Comment: I don't know, but checking the input/output heat of the cat will tell you right away. It could be a lazy sensor (B2S2). That's where I always look first anyway, because a cat is so much more expensive to replace than is the sensor. If the sensors haven't been changed lately, you might want to do that anyway. Most call for a 100k mile maintenance interval. If it's due, I'd change those out before I started worrying about anything else. Check your owner's manual for your vehicle's schedule.

Comment: Ask Schrodinger.

Comment: nice pun, BUT he is definitely dead)

Comment: Funny, I had this wacky roommate once.  He picked up a girl for a second date, and when driving away from her house, saw a cat crossing the street.  He gunned the car and tried to hit the cat.  The girl goes. that's my cat, let me out of the car.  No more date, ever again.  But no, the cat wasn't dead.

Comment: Well, he's in a box so is he @Alex?